# Error 505 when modifying htaccess for removing html extension in url

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried every tutorial and guide out there to remove the html extension on a static html site (mysite.com/page.html to mysite.com/page) and yet nothing but errors.

I always get this:

**Error 500 - Internal Server Error
An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.**

Here is what I have in my root directory .htaccess currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html  [NC,L]
```

What can I do to get it to function properly?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
##Putting one more condition here to make sure it runs only when called from external browser, to avoid possible loop.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Ravinder ,the problem is with the rule's pattern. `^(.*)$` should be `^(.*?)/?$`  where the trailing slash is matched seperately. Because it could map to an invalid link `file/.html` if / is used at the end of the URL

Comment: @AmitVerma, Thank you Amit, let me fix it now.

Comment: It should work now +1 . But there is still no need to use the first condition as the second is already there to protect the loop.